# NatTable - Display a filtered count

Tags: nattable

I have a FilterRowHeaderComposite layer where a user can input a filter to filter the displayed rows.  I also display a count of the current # of rows that are showing.

I was wondering what the best approach would be to update the displayed row count when someone inputs a filter and the number of rows change.  Would it be to capture some particular event, extend the FilterRowHeaderComposite and fire some event, etc?

Thanks!

Update:
This is what I ended up doing after Dirks comment

```
    nattable.addLayerListener(event -> {
        if (event instanceof RowStructuralRefreshEvent) {
            // Code to update count to user
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GlazedListsEventLayer` fires either a `RowStructuralRefreshEvent` or a `VisualRefreshEvent` in the UI thread the NatTable stack upwards if a list change occurs. So you can listen to that. Or you do this by creating a GlazedLists `ListEventListener` that you register on the `FilterList` and listen directly to changes on the list itself.